# A cosa è dovuta la popolarità del termine "resilienza"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Il termine “resilienza” ha [due significati](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/resilienza/) principali:

> - Nella tecnologia dei materiali, la resistenza a rottura per sollecitazione dinamica, determinata con apposita prova d’urto: prova di resilienza; valore di resilienza, il cui inverso è l’indice di fragilità.
> - In psicologia, la capacità di reagire di fronte a traumi, difficoltà, ecc.

Ho l'impressione che il termine sia sempre più usato anche in altri contesti (come in finanza o nello sport ad esempio) e questa mia impressione sembra confermata anche da [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resilienza&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresilienza%3B%2Cc0).

Il termine “resilienza” sembra avere un'origine scientifica, ma il suo uso sembra ora più comune e diffuso in altri contesti. Cosa ha contribuito a questa recente estensione del suo significato?

Comment: [Qui](http://www.osservatorioresilienza.it/la-resilienza) trovi un interessante punto di vista in ambito sociale. Anche sul [Corriere](http://www.corriere.it/sette/13_maggio_07/2013-19-ravasio-resilienza_61a1d7de-b723-11e2-8651-352f50bc2572.shtml) si trova un altro interessante articolo

Comment: @abarisome - come dire che la crisi economica ha fatto la fortuna del termine :)

Comment: Sì, sostanzialmente chi non evolve e si adatta è destinato a scomparire...

Comment: Come mostra la risposta a quest'altra tua [domanda](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397293/what-made-the-usage-of-the-figurative-meaning-of-resilience-popular), il termine inglese "resilience" viene usato da tempo in contesti diversi da quelli originari. Forse la popolarità del vocabolo in italiano è dovuta al fatto che ultimamente la lingua italiana è fortemente influenzata dall'inglese.

Comment: Certo, il termine è parte del linguaggio tecnico/scientifico. È vero, da un po' lo si sente citare anche in altri contesti. Lo si è smpre fatto, è un modo di sfoggiare vera o presunta vastità di interessi culturali.

Comment: @Charo Aggiungerei purtroppo. Con casi devastanti tipo l'uso di _domestico_ da _domestic_ al posto di _nazionale_ o _confidente_ da _confident_ al posto di _fiducioso_.

Answer (score 5):

Ho trovato in questo articolo intitolato "[Resilienza ovvero lo spregiudicato invito a innovare](https://www.che-fare.com/resilienza-ovvero-lo-spregiudicato-invito-a-innovare/)" un approfondimento sia sul significato che sulla diffusione del  termine ***resilienza*** anche in altri contesti.

In particolare:

> La prima volta che sentii utilizzare la parola resilienza fu nel 2010
>   ad un convegno che tesseva le meritate lodi della capacità della
>   cooperazione sociale di resistere all’onda d’urto della crisi. In un
>   primo momento credetti di averla confusa con le parole residenza o
>   resistenza, ma ci misi poco a raccogliere le prove che confermavano la
>   mia prima impressione. In rete si trovava già un’ampia sitografia,
>   anche se fu necessario attendere il 2013 perché in Italia la fama
>   della parola esplodesse con tutta la sua forza, attraverso una
>   lunghissima serie di post, articoli, approfondimenti ed eventi.

E qui ne viene spiegato (in maniera accademica) il processo di diffusione:

> Attraverso un processo di traslazione ([Translating organizational change , Czarniawska-Sevon, 1996](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=-czmBZcAAAAJ&citation_for_view=-czmBZcAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC); [Global ideas: how ideas, objects and practices travel in a global economy, Czarniawska-Sevon, 2005](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=-czmBZcAAAAJ&citation_for_view=-czmBZcAAAAJ:O3NaXMp0MMsC))
>   il concetto di resilienza si è spostato dall’ambito
>   tecnico-scientifico a quello dell’ecologia, della sociologia,
>   dell’economia, della psicologia etc. Marco Belpoliti (2015) ne ha
>   tracciato un’ottima sintesi in [Resilienza: l’arte di adattarsi](http://www.ariannaeditrice.it/articolo.php?id_articolo=46905).

Per quanto riguarda il riferimento di Belpoliti vale la pena soffermarsi sul seguente passaggio:

> "Resilienza" è più recente, rimonta al Settecento ("capacità di un
>   materiale di resistere agli urti senza spezzarsi"), sebbene il suo uso
>   in campo metallurgico sia del 1932. L'etimo è esplicito: "saltare
>   indietro". Tuttavia la sua apparizione nel dibattito attuale (nel web
>   ora sono migliaia i siti e gli articoli connessi al termine
>   resilience) è merito degli psicologi.
>
> Emmy Werner lo usò per la prima volta nel 1955 studiando 698 neonati
>   dell'isola Kauai nelle Hawaii nell'arco di trent'anni. Secondo la
>   psicologia tradizionale molti di loro avrebbero presentato in futuro
>   situazioni di disagio psichico, per via delle condizioni delle
>   famiglie d'origine. Werner verificò che invece 72 di loro erano
>   riusciti a migliorare le loro condizioni nell'età adulta, raggiungendo
>   un livello di vita buono. Merito della loro resilienza.